# Mysql query incredibly slow in LEFT JOIN if the given value 0 to the primary id

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

In this sql:

```
    SELECT s.*,
           u.id,
           u.name 
      FROM shops s 
 LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id 
                   OR u.id = s.owner_user_id 
     WHERE s.status = 1
```

For some reason this query takes an amazing time.  although id is the primary key.  it seems especially after I added this part `OR u.id=s.owner_user_id` the query became slow.  `owner_user_id` often is 0 only handful of times.  But why would it take so long apparently scanning the whole table?   The database table `users` is very long and big. I didn't design it. this is for a client who subsequent programmers added too many fields. the table is 22k rows and dozens of fields.

*the names of the fields for demonstration only. actual names are different, so don't ask me why I'm looking for owner_user_id (;  I did solve the slowness by remove the "OR ..." part and instead searching for the id in the loop if it is not 0.  but I would like to know why this is happening and how to speedup that query as is.

Comment: "the database table users is very long and big" - 22k rows is NOT big; it is tiny!

Comment: well there are dozens of fields which are not optimized.

Comment: the logic is to get shops list along the user info associated with a shop, the shop could have two users one or the other.   *I edited the select part.

Comment: what data are you getting from table shops?  The select clause is only asking for user fields.

Comment: I edited the select part, sorry for missing that part, I didn't paste the exact select and names. as i figured out it is not relevant and don't want to paste code of a client website, but the logic is same for the join part. when I put the OR part is amazingly slow, when I remove it, it is normal speed. their server is also messed up . still why would this exact query cause such noticeable slow down not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to speed it up by using `IN` instead of the `OR` but that is minor.

```
SELECT u.id,
           u.name 
      FROM shops s
 LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id IN ( s.user_id, s.owner_user_id )
WHERE s.status = 1
```

Firstly, are there any indexes on this table?  Mainly one on the user.id field or the s.user_id or s.owner_user_id?

However, I must ask why you need to use a LEFT JOIN instead of a regular join.  The LEFT JOIN causes the matching of every row with every other one.  And since I'm assuming the value / id should either be in the user_id or the owner_user_id field, and that there will always be a match, if that is the case then the use of a JOIN should speed the query up a bit.

And as Mitch said, 22k rows is tiny.

Comment: thanks, that's a good a suggestion, I will test that.   I did use LEFT JOIN in case there is no match but that was before I added the OR part later after which I should have returned the use of inner join, but can you please elaborate on "The LEFT JOIN causes the matching of every row with every other one".   I thought LEFT JOIN is exactly like INNER JOIN except a match is not required. maybe that's my problem.    the 22k is not tiny if you take in consideration the dozens of unoptimized messy fields.  there is already an index on user_id and owner_user_id. while u.id is primary key.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to know which user record is which? Here's how I'd do it

```
SELECT s.*,
       u.name AS user_name,
       o.name AS owner_name
FROM shops s
LEFT JOIN users u ON s.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN users o ON s.owner_user_id = o.id
WHERE s.status = 1
```

I've omitted the IDs from the user table in the `SELECT` as these will be part of `s.*` anyway.

I'm curious about the left joins too. If `shops.user_id` and `shops.owner_user_id` are required foreign keys, use inner joins instead.

Comment: thanks, well in my case I don't need to know which user record is which.  because either user_id or owner_user_id  can't be both in this case.   I agree about the left join thanks for both of your tips, but now my question why would left join be slower than inner join.